# Phone provider Plenti -> Router write 汥湴槿

Tags: translation

When I plug the SIMcard from Danish provider Plenti, my Huawei router writes the provider name as 汥湴槿

Google translate translates it into 汥 Ban hibiscus. This doesn't seem right to me... What can it mean? "Unknown provider?"

Comment: 'I Kina spiser de hunde.'

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. Unicode in hexadecimal:

   > 汥 6C65 
   >   湴 6E74 
   >   槿 69FF
2. Then, look up the ASCII chart:
   [image: ASCII]
3. Write them down:

   > 6C: l 
   >   65: e 
   >   6E: n 
   >   74: t 
   >   69: i
4. Now, We get "lenti". Don't ask why "P" is missing or why it's displayed like that. Maybe it's just a bug.